# How to automatically power on an Android COSU device when plugged in?

Tags: android, android-for-work, cosu, android-management-api

I want to setup some tablets in a way that they automatically turn on and open my application when connected in a power source. Those tablets will be all [COSU](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/) devices and my application is a single app. I have read the docs and the closest policy that I have found was `stayOnPluggedModes` in this [page](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies), and the description is not very clear (at least to me).

Unfortunately, at the moment, I am unable to test if this policy works. So, is the `stayOnPluggedModes` policy the right one for what I need? If not, what are my options (excluding everything bellow, because it voids the device warrant)?

- [Use RTC wake alarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446182/automatic-turn-on-in-android-device)
- [Replacing the battery animation script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601041/android-turn-on-a-device-programmatically)
- [Alter off-mode-charge with Fastboot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/193840/is-there-a-different-fastboot-command-for-the-google-pixel-and-the-oem-off-mode)
- [Delete system/bin/charge_only_mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294258/auto-boot-when-wall-charger-is-plugged)
- [Change the bootloader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9553589/3186218)

And also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621599/wake-android-device-up) doesn't work because it requires the device to be asleep.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Kiosk Mode, any apps defined in the **policy** will be launched automatically when a device boots. They run in full-screen mode and are typically pinned to the home screen in a way that prevents users from leaving the app.

`"kioskCustomLauncherEnabled": true`

Or Lock task mode which hides the Home and Recents buttons on a device, preventing users from escaping the app. To create a policy that supports an app with lock task mode.

```
"applications": [
  {
    "packageName": "com.example.app",
    "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
    "lockTaskAllowed": true,
    "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
  }
],
```

*Note: Lock task mode is only compatible with Android 6.0+ devices.*

`--- Edit ---`

Here's what you can try.

1. Enable `"powerManagementEventsEnabled"` available in the `"StatusReportingSettings"` of the policy. This will log events related to power source such as charger connected, disconnected etc.
2. If the device is connected to the power source, an event will be created for the same. Try and fetch the event by adding a listening event using Pub/Sub.
3. Once the event returns as Plugged In or Power Source Connected then open the apps maybe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I get that _apps defined in the policy will be launched automatically when a device boots_, but that is not my question. Sorry if I wasn't clear, but what I want is to boot the device automatically when plugged in on a power source. Currently, to overcome this problem, the devices are never shutdown, but for me this is not an ideal solution. Also, I can't provide access to the power button to the users.

Comment: The question before the edit was very different.
Anyways, I've updated my answer.

But I'm not sure if it's currently possible to boot the device automatically when plugged in on a power source.

Answer (score 0):

for some devices this works:

- boot device in fastboot mode
- open adb shell
- type: fastboot devices (check
  your device exists)
- then use fastboot command: fastboot oem-off-mode charge 0
- finally "fastboot reboot"

hope it helps.